# Rails life time of params variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, view, parameters

In the standard "index" method of controller I set some value in the params hash in order to use it in the view if it's not initialized yet in other case do nothing.

```
def index
  params[:my_value] ||= {}
end
```

when I use include? method on the params[:my_value] in the view, there's an error evaluating nil.include?

Why there's such error if params[:my_value] cannot be nil. If it's nil, its value should be initialized with {}, that's what ||= operator does. What can be the problem here?

Comment: why do you not just set an instance variable to use in your views like `@params = params[:my_value] || {}`

Comment: then why there's a params variable if we can define anything with the help of instance variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in the merge method. It turned out that

```
a = b.merge(a)
```

and

```
a.merge(b) {|key, v1, v2| v1 }
```

do different things and in the first case(which was wrong) nil appears somewhere. I haven't figured out yet why is it so because merge method always return a hash and when I replaced the first variant with the second everything was ok. So I don't see any problem...

Answer (score 0):

**rails parameters exists upto request flow completes**

You can access `params` inside view page going to be rendered but params will not be available if you are doing re-direction to another page inside controller action as it *interrupts request flow.*